# Why is readlines() reading much more than the sizehint?

Tags: python, parsing, readlines

### Background

I am parsing very large text files (30GB+) in Python 2.7.6. To speed the process up a bit, I am splitting the files into chunks and farming them out to subprocesses using the multiprocessing library. To do this, I am iterating over the file in my main process, recording byte positions where I want to split the input file and passing those byte positions to the subprocesses, which then open the input file and read in their block using `file.readlines(chunk_size)`. However, I'm finding that the chunks that are read in seem to be much larger (4x) than the `sizehint` argument.

### The Question

Why isn't the sizehint being heeded?

### Example Code

This following code demonstrates my issue:

```
import sys

# set test chunk size to 2KB
chunk_size = 1024 * 2

count = 0
chunk_start = 0
chunk_list = []

fi = open('test.txt', 'r')
while True:
    # increment chunk counter
    count += 1

    # calculate new chunk end, advance file pointer
    chunk_end = chunk_start + chunk_size
    fi.seek(chunk_end)

    # advance file pointer to end of current line so chunks don't have broken 
    # lines
    fi.readline() 
    chunk_end = fi.tell()

    # record chunk start and stop positions, chunk number
    chunk_list.append((chunk_start, chunk_end, count))

    # advance start to current end
    chunk_start = chunk_end

    # read a line to confirm we're not past the end of the file
    line = fi.readline()
    if not line:
        break

    # reset file pointer from last line read
    fi.seek(chunk_end, 0)

fi.close()

# This code represents the action taken by subprocesses, but each subprocess
# receives one chunk instead of iterating the list of chunks itself.
with open('test.txt', 'r', 0) as fi:
    # iterate over chunks
    for chunk in chunk_list:
        chunk_start, chunk_end, chunk_num = chunk

        # advance file pointer to chunk start
        fi.seek(chunk_start, 0)

        # print some notes and read in the chunk
        sys.stdout.write("Chunk #{0}: Size: {1} Start {2} Real Start: {3} Stop {4} "
              .format(chunk_num, chunk_end-chunk_start, chunk_start, fi.tell(), chunk_end))
        chunk = fi.readlines(chunk_end - chunk_start)
        print("Real Stop: {0}".format(fi.tell()))

        # write the chunk out to a file for examination
        with open('test_chunk{0}'.format(chunk_num), 'w') as fo:
            fo.writelines(chunk)
```

### Results

I ran this code with an input file (test.txt) of about 23.3KB and it produced the following output:

> Chunk #1: Size: 2052 Start 0 Real Start: 0 Stop 2052 Real Stop: 8193
>   Chunk #2: Size: 2051 Start 2052 Real Start: 2052 Stop 4103 Real Stop: 10248
>   Chunk #3: Size: 2050 Start 4103 Real Start: 4103 Stop 6153 Real Stop: 12298
>   Chunk #4: Size: 2050 Start 6153 Real Start: 6153 Stop 8203 Real Stop: 14348
>   Chunk #5: Size: 2050 Start 8203 Real Start: 8203 Stop 10253 Real Stop: 16398
>   Chunk #6: Size: 2050 Start 10253 Real Start: 10253 Stop 12303 Real Stop: 18448
>   Chunk #7: Size: 2050 Start 12303 Real Start: 12303 Stop 14353 Real Stop: 20498
>   Chunk #8: Size: 2050 Start 14353 Real Start: 14353 Stop 16403 Real Stop: 22548
>   Chunk #9: Size: 2050 Start 16403 Real Start: 16403 Stop 18453 Real Stop: 23893
>   Chunk #10: Size: 2050 Start 18453 Real Start: 18453 Stop 20503 Real Stop: 23893
>   Chunk #11: Size: 2050 Start 20503 Real Start: 20503 Stop 22553 Real Stop: 23893
>   Chunk #12: Size: 2048 Start 22553 Real Start: 22553 Stop 24601 Real Stop: 23893

Each of the chunk sizes reported is ~2KB, all of the start/stop positions line up the way they should, and the real file position reported by `fi.tell()` seem to be correct, so I'm fairly certain my chunking algorithm is good. However, the real stop locations show that `readlines()` is reading much more than the size hint. Also, output files #1 - #8 are 8.0KB, which is much larger than the size hint.

Even if my attempts to only break the chunks on line ends was wrong, `readlines()` still shouldn't have to read more than 2KB + one line. Files #9 - #12 get increasingly smaller, which makes sense since the chunk starting points get closer and closer to the end of the file, and `readlines()` won't read past the end of the file.

### Notes

1. My test input file simply has "< line number >\n" printed on each line, 1-5000.
2. I tried again with different chunk and input file sizes with similar results.
3. The [readlines documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) says that read sizes may be rounded up to the size of an internal buffer, so I've tried opening the files without buffering (as shown) and it made no difference.
4. I am using this algorithm to split the file because I need to be able to support *.bz2 and *.gz compressed files, and *.gz files have no way for me to identify the uncompressed file size without decompressing the file. *.bz2 files don't either, but I could seek 0 bytes from the end of those and use `fi.tell()` to get the file size. See [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25734252/2615940).
5. Before the requirement to support compressed files was added, the previous version of the script used `os.path.getsize()` as a stopping condition on the chunking loop, and readlines seemed to work just fine with that method.

Comment: it does say size*hint* and not *size*...

Comment: @monkut True, but there's no reason it should read 8KB when I suggested 2KB, assuming it doesn't have to read another 6KB to read a complete line. It should read the suggested number of bytes plus however many are needed to reach the next newline character only. Also, as I mentioned in my notes, readlines used to follow the sizehint until I changed my chunking algorithm.

Comment: Real stop is at most a few kB more than your expected stop. This is a pretty tiny amount with a modern CPU and GiB of memory, and may be due to the vastly improved efficiency of allocating memory in page-sized chunks or larger on most OSes. How exactly is it a problem for your program?

Comment: it seems your incrementing by `.readline()` and lines are delimited by the linefeed.  While you assumption is that a linefeed appears around 2KB, the linefeed placement is arbitrary.

Comment: @DanLenski It's a problem because that means I am reading the same data multiple times. I am trying to split the file into non-overlapping chunks for processing by subprocesses, otherwise I will end up with duplicate data when I actually process the results of the file parsing. Also, this is a small example file of the issue I'm seeing. My real input files can be tens of gigabytes.

Comment: @Scott, thanks for explaining. Here's a possible, partial solution: use `fi.read(chunk_size)` to strictly limit the size of the data read. Then either (a) chop that string at the last EOL character(s) or (b) plunk it into an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) and read line-by-line from there, before dumping it into your individual-chunk file.

Comment: @monkut I agree that new lines can be at arbitrary locations through the file. I'm not really making an assumption about their placement, though. The 2KB marks are just where I want to start looking for the next line break, and split the file when I find it. If that means I end up with a 3KB chunk because of a ridiculously long line, I'm fine with that. I just need to know that the chunks don't break lines.

Comment: Make sure your task isn't I/O-bound, because if it is, none of this multiprocessing will help you.

Comment: @user2357112 That is an excellent suggestion, but I have already done so.

Comment: Just because you _request_ x bytes, doesn't mean that it has to actually _read_ x bytes. It may read as much as it deems necessary to make adequate use of available buffers or the read fits nicely within page boundaries. As long is it actually returns the x bytes you requested (possibly less), it's working as I would expect. And again, it's a _hint_, not a rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer the `readlines` documentation mentions isn't related to the buffering that the third argument of the `open` call controls. The buffer is [this buffer in `file_readlines`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7b0fdc1e917a/Objects/fileobject.c#l1661):

```
static PyObject *
file_readlines(PyFileObject *f, PyObject *args)
{
    long sizehint = 0;
    PyObject *list = NULL;
    PyObject *line;
    char small_buffer[SMALLCHUNK];
```

where `SMALLCHUNK` is defined earlier:

```
#if BUFSIZ < 8192
#define SMALLCHUNK 8192
#else
#define SMALLCHUNK BUFSIZ
#endif
```

I don't know where `BUFSIZ` comes from, but it looks like you're getting the `#define SMALLCHUNK 8192` case. In any case, `readlines` will never use a buffer smaller than 8 KiB, so you should probably make your chunks bigger than that.

Comment: This seems promising, but I ran my tests with a 16KB chunk size on a test file of ~150KB, and the chunks were rounded up to 24KB. Is there anything to suggest that readlines() will read to the nearest *multiple* of the buffer size?

Comment: @ScottLawson: If you're thinking of code that suggests it, then yes. (It's a bit more complicated than that, though.) If you're thinking of documentation, that's how I read the "possibly after rounding up to an internal buffer size" line. In any case, 2 KiB is tiny. The behavior you're seeing is like asking for a photocopy of the first paragraph on a book page and getting a photocopy of the whole page, or asking for 2 pages and a paragraph and getting 3 pages. It's not that unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but perhaps will help...

I have a feeling there is probably a better way to *chunk* your file, which would bypass your current issue.  Just a thought, but since a file can be iterated, would something like this work?

```
import bzip2
import gzip
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count


def chunker(filepath):
    """define and yield chunks"""
    if filepath.endswith(".bz"):
        read_open = bzip2.open
    elif filepath.endswith(".gz"):
        read_open = gzip.open

    with read_open(filepath) as in_f:        
        delim = "something"
        chunk = []
        for line in in_f:
            if delim not in line:
                chunk.append(line)
            else:
                current, next_ = line.split(delim)
                chunk.append(current)
                yield chunk
                chunk = [next_]
        if chunk:
            yield chunk

def process_chunk(chunk):
    # do magic
    return 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = ""
    chunk_iter = chunker(filepath)

    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count() - 1)
    for result in pool.imap(process_chunk, chunk_iter , chunksize=1)
        print result
```

or if your already using 1-pass to read and generate the list of chunks, why not write out the separate chunks as separate files as you read (if you have the disk space).  Then you can just give a worker pool a list of filepaths to process.

Or, if your workers are fast enough to process the chunks and you have the memory, you could just pass the whole chunk to a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) as you read.  And the workers can pull chunks from the Queue.

Comment: what is the largest chunk size?

Comment: Unfortunately your code snippet won't work for me. In addition to needing to make sure the chunks don't break lines, I also need to look at the actual content of the lines and only break the chunks between certain markers. I just left that out of this example to keep it shorter. I will look into your last suggestion though. Maybe keeping the lines in memory once they're there would be a better way to go...

Comment: It's up to me. I was planning on playing with the chunk size after getting something working to see what gets me the shortest run time. Fortunately, I have some pretty hefty computing resources available so the working memory footprint isn't much of an issue, so keeping many large chunks in memory at once shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: you could feed `pool.imap()` a chunk iterator if you don't want to fool around with queues.