# How to get size of `.sdcard` file which is compressed using bz2 (sdcard.bz2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, bz2

I have `sdcard.bz2` file and used the Python's  tarfile library to extract the file, I get an invalid header error.

Is there a way to extract files in `bz2` archive and to read the size of that file.

I have tried extracting it using `7zip` and I am able to extract it without any issue but I need library or script to Extract file, to extract data I have used python's `bz2` but I can't read the size if that file.

Comment: Is it a bz2 or is it a tar?

Comment: It is .sdcard file compressed using bz2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python bz2 uncompressed file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647738/python-bz2-uncompressed-file-size)